# jquery desktop blocking input and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to modify this: [jquery desktop](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-desktop)

by adding a input field inside one of the windows. However, I can't type anything into the input. I opened firebug and the classes are flashing when I click the text input so I'm guessing that's what's blocking it. But I don't know how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: @silverbandit isn't trying to modify 'this link text', but 'this:' followed by the link. The link's blue can be easy to miss, and the link is important for the post.

Comment: I'v edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his very long article, do a page search for 'Cancel mousedown'. You'll see he's canceled any mousedown event that's not a link. That's what you'll have to alter to make it usable. You could either delete the whole thing (the point was to bind a context menu, which he ended up not doing) or add `input` as an exception like `a` is.